# Existence of finite output of a system

Tags: frequency, linear-systems, periodic

1.If frequently response of a LTI system  exist and  finite then  can we say that, for a periodic or non periodic input signal,  output is also finite?
2.if responses(output) of LTI 
system for sinusoids of all the frequencies(inputs),  exist and finite at steady state then we can say that it's frequency response must exist whether system is stable or unstable?

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.